# "Welcome on my website" or "Welcome to my website"

Tags: prepositions, expressions

I want to know how to say "Bienvenu sur mon site" in English.

I hesitate between the preposition **to** and the preposition **on**

> Welcome **to** my website!

or

> Welcome **on** my website!

I've found on [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/bienvenue+sur+mon+site.html) that the two preposition are used indistinctly.

So what is the correct form?

Comment: I think it's more common to say "welcome to".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Welcome on" is not idiomatic. **Use "welcome to" in your case.**

Answer (score -1):

Imagine you are welcoming a visitor to your house, would you say

> "welcome on my house"

No you wouldn't.

You always introduce or welcome people to things: websites, houses, people etc.