# What is the full expression of "welcome to X"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, spoken-english, greetings

We can say "Welcome to" + a place, like "[Welcome to my website](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/192346/10484)" or "[Welcome to Berlin](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/237292/10484)", to greet someone, but I don't know what the complete expression of "welcome to" is since it lacks a subject and a verb.

I wonder if "Welcome to X" is equal to "You are welcome to X"? If so, can "you are welcome" be used in scenarios of greeting? For instance, the following conversation:

A: "I am planing to visit your country next week"
B: "You are very welcome!"

Comment: There isn't a 'full expression'. As a greeting, _welcome_ means something like "It is good to see you here'. _You are welcome_ is usually a response to thanks, meaning "I was happy to give you this thing/do this thing for you".

Comment: @KateBunting OK, I thought it is not a complete sentence

Comment: The greeting "Welcome" effectively *means* "You are welcome" (your coming / arrival is good), but the "I am glad to have helped you" sense has become idiomatically established for the fully-articulated sentence, leaving the one-word form as just a greeting. Like "Hello", except "Welcome" is only suitable when greeting a visitor about to enter your current location, *with your approval*.

Comment: Here is an article on this issue: ['You Are Most Welcome': Meaning, Definition, Examples](https://writingtips.org/you-are-most-welcome/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Welcome to X* isn't a shortened form of anything. "Welcome!" as a greeting means something like "It's good to see you here". (Oxford Languages says it is derived from Old English words meaning 'pleasure' and 'come').

*You are welcome* is usually said in response to thanks - "I'm glad for you to have [the thing I've just given you]" or "I was happy to do this favour for you".

Comment: But we can say 'something is welcome' to mean 'something is appreciated' as answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2128/103221), then it does not apply to human. Right?

Comment: Oxford gives, as the first definition of _welcome_ as an adjective, _(of a guest or new arrival) gladly received.
"I'm pleased to see you, lad—you're welcome"_. However, it doesn't feel quite right to say _You are welcome_ with reference to a future visit. I think B would say "You will be very welcome".